# Draft answer fills "Your Answer" text area for all questions on mobile site

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers, mobile-web, draft

On the mobile site, if you have a draft answer stored on the server, it fills the "Your Answer" text area of each question that you visit, not just the question that the draft applies to.

On the full site, if you begin answering a question, your answer is auto-saved after a minute or so and stored on the server as a draft.  If you navigate away from the page to a different question, the "Your Answer" text area will be blank on the new page.  If you return to the first question again, your draft answer will again be displayed in "Your Answer".

However on the mobile site, once you have a draft answer, it is displayed in the "Your Answer" text area for any question on the site.  This sends unnecessary bytes and risks the user submitting an answer to an inappropriate question.

Since the user would have to "Select All" and "Cut" anyway to start answering a different question, the "Your Answer" text area should only be filled in with the draft answer if the question matches the question that the draft applies to.  This would make the mobile site consistent with the full site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The draft system is actually different between mobile and desktop sites, relying on localStorage instead of post-backs when on the mobile site.  This is to shave bytes, and to remove concerns about drafts being lost due to unreliable connectivity on mobile devices.

Anyway, that actual bug was that the localStorage key wasn't incorporating the question id when saving answer drafts.  This will be fixed with the next deployment.